# "Request module" causing issues while doing the get request, on the middleware that uses "connect" in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node.js-connect

I am using [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) at the client side to perform a  REST get request where middleware is [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) which then routes the request to my node server that serves it. The issue is that i tried to use the option `json:true` while making a request using the request module, So that i do not need to parse and validate the response body i receive. But unfortunately it doesn't reach the server as it fails in the middleware(connect) itself saying "Invalid JSON", since it seems to validate for JSON (when there is no request body) due to the content-type set by the request module.

Here is a request that i make using request module.

```
  request(
    {
        uri: myurl,
        json: true, //issue area
        headers: {
             //some headers. but no content-type sepcified
        }
    }
    , function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body); 
        //Here body comes as object if json:true (not for get as it fails in validation at connect middleware itself), else i need to perform JSON.parse(body).
      });
```

Here is definition for `json` property in the settings of request module (from the documentation).

> json - sets body but to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the response body as json.

But obviously it is a `GET` request and there won't be any `content-type` that i would set (But with json:true option request module seems to be setting it internally).

I could trace this down through connect's json.js snippet below

```
return function json(req, res, next) {
    if (req._body) return next();
    req.body = req.body || {};
    // check Content-Type
     //This guy fails because content-type is set as application/json by request module internally
    if ('application/json' != utils.mime(req)) return next();

    // flag as parsed
    req._body = true;

    // parse
    limit(req, res, function(err){
      if (err) return next(err);
      var buf = '';
      req.setEncoding('utf8');
      req.on('data', function(chunk){ buf += chunk });
      req.on('end', function(){
    //Here the problem area obviously buf[0] is undefined
        if (strict && '{' != buf[0] && '[' != buf[0]) return next(utils.error(400, 'invalid json'));
        try {
         ......
```

Clearly this is not an issue with connect, but it is probably an incomplete functionality provided with `json:true` property. I know that i can just set `json:false` and parse the response (JSON) to javascript object using `JSON.parse()` but i get this flexibility for other request types (when setting json:true) that i do not need to validate or parse the JSON to object manually instead i get it as object from request module's complete callback.

I would like to know if there is any other option where i can get the response body as object without these issues caused by failure in connect, or any other information on this feature that justifies this behavior with `json:true` (I couldn't find any), or any other solution that anyone has used, or any satisfactory explanation on this also is appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe headers is conflicting with json:true. json:true adds an accept header too. Try removing the headers.

Comment: @user568109 Infact i dont add any headers other than my own ones and they dont conflict. Problem is once it is out of my hands request module sets them especially the content-type which causes the issue, how can i remove them?

Comment: I get your problem now, it seems json: true option expects user to set body themselves. So can you try like this `json:{}` or `body:{}` with `json:true`.  This should work hopefully.

Comment: @user568109 Yes that is a workaround. Infact i found out that they have fixed this issue in the latest version of request module. It no longer sets the content-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer if somebody else go through the same issue.

Looking at the request module source, it seems to be a bug which has already been fixed in the latest version of request. So if you are using an older version (mine was 2.0.5) consider upgrading it a newer one.

Older one had  the following code, so no matter the json is true and no body has been set explicitly it still used to set the `content-type` as header.

```
 if (options.json) {
    options.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json' //<-- this is being set always
    if (typeof options.json === 'boolean') {
      if (typeof options.body === 'object') options.body = JSON.stringify(options.body)
    } else {
      options.body = JSON.stringify(options.json)
    }
  ......
```

With the latest version this changes:

```
  if (options.json) {
    self.json(options.json)

 //...More code 
 //and in json function

 this._json = true
  if (typeof val === 'boolean') {
    if (typeof this.body === 'object') {
      this.body = safeStringify(this.body)
      self.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json') //<-- sets it only if there is a body
    }
  } else {
    this.body = safeStringify(val)
    self.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
  }
```